# Using array in 'if' loop trouble?

Tags: java

While going about a challenge I found online for programmers to find the sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000, I ran into a problem. Here is my code:

```
public class Challenge {

    public static int i = 0;
    public static int counter = 0;
    public static int sum = 0;
    public static int[] multiples3;
    public static int[] multiples5;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        multiples3 = new int[1000];
        multiples5 = new int[1000];

        while(counter < 1000) {

            multiples3[counter] = 3*counter;
            multiples5[counter] = 5*counter;

            System.out.println("Adding: " + sum + ", " + multiples5[counter] + ", and " + multiples3[counter]);
            sum = sum + (multiples5[counter] + multiples3[counter]);
            counter++;

            System.out.println("Progressive Sum: " + sum + "\n" + "____________");

            if(multiples5[counter] >= 1000) {
                System.out.println("++++ FIVES DONE ++++");

                while(multiples3[counter] <= 999) {

                    sum = (sum + multiples3[counter]);
                    counter++;

                    System.out.println("Progressive Sum: " + sum + "\n" + "____________");

                    if(multiples3[counter] >= 999) {
                        System.out.println("~~~~~~ DONE ~~~~\n Final result: " + sum);
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on this line: `if(multiples5[counter] >= 1000) {`

I am assuming it has something to do with me trying to use an array, but I am not entirely sure as I am new to arrays. Also, am I even going about this challenge the correct way? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Don't "assume" what the error is, READ THE MESSAGE

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: `"Using array in 'if' loop trouble?"` -- there's no such animal as an "if *loop*", you know.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You are missing a `}` after the `"++++ FIVES DONE ++++"` line.

Comment: You can solve this in a single loop without using arrays.

Comment: You're getting downvoted primarily for failing to quote the error message.

Answer (score 3):

The error you face is `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. Watching `counter`:

```
while(counter < 1000) {                  counter is 999

    // your code here                    
    counter++;                           counter + 1 => 1000
    // your code here   
    if(multiples5[counter] >= 1000) {    multiples5 doesn't have 1000th index.
```

Comment: Thanks mate, the reason I couldn't read the error is because Eclipse bugged out in debug mode and wouldn't tell me. :/

Comment: @NoneNone - Then you should have first asked the question of why Eclipse was failing to give you the exception message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the line you are talking about.

The full exception on my computer is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
    at Challenge.main(Challenge.java:25)
```

Line 25:

```
if(multiples5[counter] >= 1000) {
```

This is telling you that you tried to index spot 1000. However for `multiples5` 1000 is not a valid index since its length is 1000. Valid index range only from 0 to 999.

The reason counter hits 1000 is that on the last iteration of the while loop counter starts at 999 but then you increment it to 1000. Then from that point each time you try and index the array you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
  while(counter < 1000) {
      ...
      counter++;
      ...
      if(multiples5[counter] >= 1000) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum if multiple of 3 or 5 is the sample as the sum all 3 + sum of all 5 - sum of 3*5 (otherwise they would be counted twice.  To calculate the sum of multiples you can use the formula `m * n * (n + 1) / 2` where `m` is the multiple and `n` is the number of these elements.

i.e. the sum is

```
int sum = 3 * (1000 / 3) * (1000 / 3 + 1) / 2 
        + 5 * (1000 / 5) * (1000 / 5 + 1) / 2
        - 15 * (1000 / 15) * (1000 / 15 + 1) / 2;
```

BTW It is the sum of values which are multiple of 3 or 5, not the sum of the first 1000 multiples of 3 plus the sum of the first 1000 multiples of 5.  This would sum some numbers twice as well.

So you don't need a loop or array.  Note: many of these sort of puzzle are very mathematical rather programming puzzles.